# Denormalizing with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm wondering how to properly query denormalized data with AngularFire.

I've read:
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html and  [AngularFire - How do I query denormalised data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392765/angularfire-how-do-i-query-denormalised-data)

From the link above, the following example is given.

```
{
  links: {
    link1: {
      title: "Example",
      href: "http://example.org",
      submitted: "user1",
      comments: {
        comment1: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do you save `comment1:true`, **with AngularFire**?
And how do you query that with AngularFire?

Comment: Self-fix: `syncData('links/' + linkId + '/comments/' + commentId).$set(true)`. It was the `$set(true)` that I needed to find.