# AngularFire 0.82 - How to query denormalised data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

This question is similar to [AngularFire - How do I query denormalised data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22392765/532517) but I really do want an answer that uses [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html) (current version is 0.82).
This is an example of the data structure I use:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user1": {
      "name": "Alice",
      "lists": {
        "list1": "true"
      }
    },
    "user2": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "lists": {
        "list2": "true"
      }
    }
  },
  "lists": {
    "list1": {
      "title": "Example"
    },
    "list2": {
      "title": "Example2"
    }
  }
}
```

or, in a different notation:
to get all of one user's lists we need all of these:

```
users/$userID/lists/$listID
```

and the lists' content is stored under:

```
lists/$listID
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to access the content of a specific user's lists, but without "manually" iterating over each $ListID.

An even nicer answer can include code that wraps that access in an AngularFire extended service, similar to the code under "Creating AngularFire Services" at [AngularFire docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-creating-angularfire-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help (as it always does) to understand the use case we're trying to resolve rather than simply the solution you've picked to the problem--there are often simpler ways to approach the problem set (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)).

There is nothing built into AngularFire to handle nested lists of lists. A list of specific elements would actually be quite a bit easier than several lists referenced from a list.

### Firebase.util

A tool called [Firebase.util](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/) exists to help with denormalization (it's currently getting revved to V2, due out in a month or two), and it's compatible with AngularFire:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase(URL);
var indexRef = fbRef.child('users/' + userId + '/lists');
var dataRef = fbRef.child('lists');
var joinedRef = Firebase.util.intersection(indexRef, dataRef);

var lists = $firebase( joinedRef ).$asArray();
```

### Angular only

An angular-only approach would be to load the lists by hand and utilize AngularFire for the individual lists:

```
app.factory('NestedList', function($firebase, $timeout) {
   return function(indexRef, dataRef) {
      var hashOfLists = {};
      indexRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
         var key = snap.key();
         var list = $firebase( dataRef.child(key).$asArray();
         hashOfLists[key] = list;
      });
      indexRef.on('child_removed', function(snap) {
         $timeout(function() {
            delete hashOfLists[snap.key()];
         });
      });
      return hashOfLists;
   }
});
```

**note that this example uses snap.key(), but that only applies when using version 2.x of the SDK, which was just released this week; prev versions should use snap.name()**

For more advanced operations and to create your own directives or services, check out the [question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047958/is-it-possible-to-sortcompare-and-reverse-an-array-in-angularfire/26051475?noredirect=1#comment40837121_26051475). Although it may not appear at first glance, this is a pretty thorough discussion of how to take any Firebase data and transform it into any proprietary structure.

Comment: Thank you for an answer I can learn from :) Regarding the XY problem, that was intentional. My question was indeed regarding the specific solution, and not about the original problem. I can re-arrange the data, but I wanted to learn from this how to better code using AngularFire.

Comment: wouldn't the Firebase.util example retrieve **all** Lists that exist? That's incredibly inefficient.

Comment: It should only retrieve items in the first list when you use intersection. Join would retrieve all items in all references.